# How do I predict time using regression methods here?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I want to predict the time (in minutes) based on this 2D feature matrix that I'm given. I have preprocessed the data well and understand some basics of regression (assuming this is the best way to handle the task), but what are some of the latest state of the art approaches that can best deal with this?

For context: data on logistics/warehouse, a fair amount of categories making the data sparse. I have some intuition that perhaps I should look into a probabilistic model, where I assume my target variable has some distribution, and define a loss accordingly. Is this a wise choice?

From some brief research, using MSE seem to be "ok" but not really appropriate for time (since there's no negative time). Could someone give some pointers where should I look into?

Comment: Poisson and Negative Binomial are good for counts that can't be negative.

Comment: Apart from non-negativity, why does Poisson work? Since it assumes the distribution model *counts*, but in this case, there wouldn't be a "count" of time; am I missing something? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Don't you have a count of number of minutes?

Comment: Or if it is time until something happens, consider Survival Analysis.